# PHP (Laravel): Get Object inside (nested) Array by value

Tags: php, json, laravel, post

I have a local JSON File inside my Laravel Storage. Currently I have a controller method, where I receive these values:

```
    $category = $request->format;
    $company = $request->author;
```

via a post request, i.e. 'Mikrofon' && 'Sony'.

I want to use these both values in order to search inside my array for the objects, where format or author (only one needs to be true) has the expected value I get from my post.

At the end, I wanna show a price and a product description from the found object and send the data back to my blade view.

My array looks Like this: 
[image: array]

My post Req. looks like this:
[image: post]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the collection's [first](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first) method, giving a function that will pass a truth test, if it passes, it returns that item.

```php
$foundItem = $collection->first(function ($item) use ($request) {
    return $item->format === $request->format || $item->author === $request->author;
});
```

Please, check that `$foundItem` is not null (if it did not find any it will)

---

You can also type hint the `$item` so your IDE autocomplets anything and follows ot and also you are sure PHP will have that type in the collection. `function (Item $item) ...`